# Is Pandas.DataFrame.sample(n=batch_size) a good way to get batch data?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find an alternative to built-in implementations like `mnist.train.next_batch(BATCH_SIZE)`

While trying to implement a function that returns a batch of data, I found `pd.sample(n)` and it seems to do the work fine.

But I was wondering if there are any caveats in using `pd.sample()` for machine learning?

Cheers.

Comment: Is this from tensorflow? `mnist.train.next_batch(BATCH_SIZE)`

Comment: Yes, Tensorflow. But I only used it as an example of getting the next batch of data.

Comment: If you're working on tensorflow, my recommendation would be not to mix and match APIs.

Comment: Thank you coldspeed. Do you mean use a TF API to get batch data? I will check if there are TF API that I can use to retrieve a batch of data from a Pandas DF.

Comment: I mean to say if you are working with tensorflow, stick to Tensorflow for the batching... else Wen's suggestion is fine.

Comment: Thank you. I am using TF but have my own data set loaded on a DataFrame. So I am looking for an easier way to get the next batch of data, without writing my own function.

Comment: You should convert that DataFrame to a BatchDataset tensor using `df.train.tensor_from_slices` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend  using

```
sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold
```

Base on the doc : Provides train/test indices to split data in train test sets.

This cross-validation object is a variation of KFold that returns stratified folds. The folds are made by ***preserving the percentage of samples for each class.***

If you are using the `resample` . For example for a classifier model, it is hard to make each sub data contains all the classes.

Comment: Thank you. Would this have any advantage in a simple case like a data set of MNIST?

Comment: @madu it is depends on what kind of algorithms you want to implement , However since we already have this in sklearn why just not go straightforward

Comment: Thanks Wen. Right. Yes, I haven't seen using pd.sample() as a way of getting next batch of data, so was curious if something not right about it.